# How would you create a unique session Id for each connection when the Session State is off?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

as stated in the question we are planning to turn session state off, and we do have a number of instances of our app that run on different servers.

to create a unique session id, we can use the following code:

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
string newSessionId =  manager.CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);
```

but since our apps run on different servers there could potentially be duplicate ids created for different users.

is it possible to make session id absolutely unique across a web farm or is there an alternative to session id as a unique id across a web farm.

Comment: Never been in ASP.NET but If you can set a server environment variable, read it out , and use it as a prefix: string newSessionId =  SERVER_PREFIX +  manager.CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);

Comment: @user3790680 we have a redis server, I was thinking of getting a unique id from redis and assigning it as the session id or prepend it like you have done